# Why does the su command does not work without sudo

Tags: su

I know it might seem lame but i was just wondering why do we need a sudo command to use su cmd to switch to root user.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not enable login for the root user per default. Which is why you can not switch to root using `su`, but become root using `sudo`.